# Return String from Java to Ajax does not work correctly

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

From Java I return a string to Ajax

```
return "ehy";
```

From Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "getNote", 
    }).done(function(principal){
        alert(principal);
    }).error(function(xhr) {
        manageError(xhr); 
    });
```

> alert says: ""ehy"";

Why four apexes?

I would **ehy**, instead the **content** of principal is **"ehy"**.

Comment: This could be a server-side data binding issue. If you are using a binding mechanism that marshals your return values to JSON, and your return value already is of type "String", then you can end up with the addtl. double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the return type in the function, I guess you defined a String as return type.
        return ehy;

should work if you defined String as return value.

Comment: Can you post the function you are getting  return "ehy"; from?

Comment: It's a simple method with this signature: `public @ResponseBody String getNote()` that returns a string: `return "ehy";`